# How is できれば used in this sentence?

Tags: conjugations, keigo

> 申し訳ありません。
> あなたのシャツが破れているのを それとなく お伝えできれば

I understand the sentence itself is "I thought I had to inform you about the fact your shirt is torn."

But why is きれば here used instead of just 伝えれば?

Answer (score 1):

伝える becomes お伝えする in the humble form, which shows respect towards the object person involved in the action, then, it further conjugates into お伝えできる in the potential form, which stands for one’s ability, that is, “if I can tell you”.